# Compare CSVs and remove all duplicates that appear from first

Tags: python

I have two CSV files (A and B). I need to be able to remove any row in CSV-A if it shares the same value with a row in CSV-B. I only need to compare the first column item (email) and then remove the row if it exists in CSV-B. Is there a simple way of doing this?

I've done something similar in Powershell but want to do this in Python

```
$fileA = Import-csv '.\CSV-A.csv'
$fileB = Import-csv '.\CSV-B.csv'

$deduped = Compare-Object -Ref $fileA -Diff $fileB -Property email -PassThru | 
  Where-Object Sideindicator -eq '<=' | 
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Sideindicator

$deduped
$deduped | Export-csv '.\deduped-output-file.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

With the content of **`a.csv`**:

```
email1@gmail.com,val1,val2
email2@gmail.com,val1,val2
email3@gmail.com,val1,val2
```

and **`b.csv`**:

```
different1@gmail.com,val1,val2
email2@gmail.com,val1,val2
different2@gmail.com,val1,val2
```

The script:

```
import csv

with open('a.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_a, \
    open('b.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_b, \
    open('export.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_export:

    csvreader_a = csv.reader(f_a, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    csvreader_b = csv.reader(f_b, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    emails_to_remove = set(email for email, *_ in csvreader_b)

    csvwriter = csv.writer(f_export, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for email, *rest in csvreader_a:
        if email in emails_to_remove:
            continue
        csvwriter.writerow([email] + rest)
```

Produces **`export.csv`**:

```
email1@gmail.com,val1,val2
email3@gmail.com,val1,val2
```